# acessar apps no heroku dando erro

Tags: heroku, socket.io, node.js

bom galera eu estou tentando instalar um apps no heroku mas nao estou obtendo conseguindo visualiar o status do meu apps meu apps é um servidor em node.js e socket.io no heroku existe a opçao de deploy pelo site que se conecta no git hub até ai tranquilo mas quando digito o ip do heroku que eu acredito ser o endereço da pagina do app seguido da porta do servidor que esta escutando na porta 8000 nao me retorna nada.

é esse:

https://serverjs.herokuapp.com/

seria uma conexao remota meu cliente fica em casa e meu servidor fica no heroku mas nao consigo estabelecer conexao e nem sei se ele esta funcionando pois nao só tem uns arquivinhos la.

se voces quiserem da uma olhada acessa o meu servidor no git hub pelo seguinte link e me diz oque esta errado.

https://github.com/ktinho456/server

quando tento colocar isso no meu cliente que esta na minha casa da esse erro:

Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://serverjs.herokuapp.com:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1434420923284. (Motivo: a requisição CORS falhou).

sera que o meu cliente tem que esta na mesma maquina do servidor ?

Comment: Acho que tens de ativar CORS, dá uma olhada aqui: https://gist.github.com/codeshrew/8926379#file-cors-options-node-js

Comment: sim mas a pagina que voce me indicou tem uns codigos, oque eu faço co esses codigos crio um js e mando pro heroku ou implanto no meu servidor.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar em seu servidor node.js o módulo [**cors**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
E tente adicioná-lo desta forma:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express();

app.use(cors());

//rotas abaixo
```

Caso ainda não dê certo, configure o **cors** desta forma:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express();


var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*'
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//rotas abaixo
```

Comment: Como focaria com o cors adicionado? Tentei aqui e nao funcionou o arquivo esta no mesmo git hub do link